# Host file make a unique file for all servers

Tags: sorting, awk

I have many hosts files. I collect them from all servers and i put them together in host_files.txt and then I must make one hosts file for all servers.

I do this command to make a unique file, but some rows share the same ip address or hostname.

```
awk '!a[$0]++' host_files.txt
```

Here is my host_files.txt

```
#backup server IPs
95.23.23.56
95.23.23.57 

#ftp server IPs
45.89.67.5 
45.89.67.3 

#apache
12.56.35.36 
12.56.35.35 

#ftp server IPs
95.23.23.50

#apache
12.56.35.37
```

I want to output file, but I need to keep the comment line

```
#backup server IPs <= comment line, i need to keep them
95.23.23.56 
95.23.23.57 

#ftp server IPs <= comment line, i need to keep them
45.89.67.5 
45.89.67.3 
95.23.23.50

#apache <= comment line, i need to keep them
12.56.35.36
12.56.35.35 
12.56.35.37
```

i already try :

```
sort -ur host_files.txt

cat host_files.txt | uniq > ok_host.txt
```

I need the ip without # just need ip adresse please help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In GNU awk for using multidimensional arrays:

```
$ awk '
/^#/ { k=$0; next }          # group within identical comments, k is key to hash
/./  { a[k][$1]=$0 }         # remove empty records and hash ips
END  { for(k in a) {         # after everything, output
           print k
           for(i in a[k]) 
               print a[k][i]
     }
}' file*
#apache
12.56.35.35 #apacheprivate
12.56.35.36 #apachepub
12.56.35.37 #apachepub
#ftp server IPs
45.89.67.3 #ftpssh
45.89.67.5 #ftpmain
95.23.23.50 #ftp
#backup server IPs
95.23.23.56 #masterbasckup
95.23.23.57 #agentbasckup
```

The output is random order because of `for(k in a)`, ie. comment groups and ips within groups are in no particular order.

Comment: @ James Brown thx for your responde but it not work for me . i try "awk '/^#/{k=$0;next}/./{a[k][$1]=$0}END{for(k in a){print k; for(i in a[k]) print a[k][i]}}' host_files.txt i have this error message  : syntax error  Context is:
>>>     /^#/{k=$0;next}/./{a[k][        <<<

Comment: Do you have GNU awk?

Comment: can i do with nawk?

Comment: Sorry, had to step out for a sec. If you use nawk, try @EdMorton's solution on it. Mine only works with GNU awk. Also, if possible, consider checking out gawk, it's got some nice features.

Comment: Because you use IP-address as key, you may loose a comment if the IP is mentioned twice.

Comment: @ULick That is true and easily fixed by changing `$1` to `$0`.

Comment: @ James Brown the scripts works fine but i don't need the ip with # just need  ip adresse please help me

Comment: Well in that case set `a[k][$1]=$1` instead of `a[k][$1]=$0`.

Comment: @ James Brown i tested your codes but many duplicated lines are founnd. I just need to sorting  the ip adresse thanks

Comment: How about you post some sample that creates duplicates and we'll see. The sample in the OP is not enough to create such condition.

Answer (score 1):

This will work in any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^#/ { key = $0; next }
NF && !seen[$0]++ {
    ips[key] = ips[key] $0 ORS
}
END {
    for (key in ips) {
        print key ORS ips[key]
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
#apache
12.56.35.36 #apachepub
12.56.35.35 #apacheprivate
12.56.35.37 #apachepub

#ftp server IPs
45.89.67.5 #ftpmain
45.89.67.3 #ftpssh
95.23.23.50 #ftp

#backup server IPs
95.23.23.56 #masterbasckup
95.23.23.57 #agentbasckup
```

Output order will be random due to use of the `in` operator, if that's a problem it's just a couple more lines of code to change.

Comment: That's very nice.

Answer (score 0):

If awk is not a requirement.

```
#!/bin/ksh

cat host_files.txt | while read line ; do
    [[ $line =~ ^$ ]] && { continue; }              # skip empty lines
    [[ $line =~ ^# ]] && { group=$line; continue; } # remember the group name
    print "$group|$line"                            # print with group name in front
done | sort  \
    | while read line ; do
        if [[ ${line%\|*} != $last ]]; then         # if the group name changed
            print "\n${line%\|*}"                   #  print the group name
            last=${line%\|*}                        #  remember the new group name
        fi
        print "${line#*\|}"                         # print the entry without the group name
    done
```

- put the group name in front of the line
- sort
- detect changing group name and print it
- print entry without group name

Using the same concept with awk (avoiding the while loop in shell).

```
awk '
    /^#/ { k=$0; next }
    /./  { print k "|" $0 }
' host_files.txt |   sort   | awk -F '|' '{
        if ( k != $1 ) { print "\n" $1; k = $1; }
        print $2
    }' -
```

Because it does not use an array it would not loose lines due to duplicate keys.

And, thinking a bit more, the second awk can be avoided. Adding the key to each line. For the header without 'x'. So the header is sorted above the rest. In the output, just remove the added sort-key.

```
awk '
    /^#/ { k=$0; print k "|" $0; next; }
    /./  { print k "x|" $0 }
' t18.dat  |   sort -u   | cut -d '|' -f 2
```

Comment: Whether awk is a requirement or not it's the right tool for the job. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for some of the reasons why (and also google UUOC).

Comment: You are right about the UUOC. But it makes the dataflow more obvious  (Okay, it is not the strongest argument).

Comment: Just wanted to add a different approach, without reading the whole input into memory and printing at the end. But two awk running and a sort in the middle may be worth.

Comment: @ULick sorry the script works fine but many duplicates lines are there

Comment: Are you sure they are not in the input ?   Removing duplicates can be done by adding  `-u`  to the sort